# Apache: mod_rewrite not directing one address

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm writing a web based program, and instead of having a mass of `/?p=54&z=42`, etc in the URL, I've set it up to direct the first "directory" (eg `/home/`) to be the function, the second "directory" (eg `/home/view/`) to be the action.

Right now, setting it as `localhost/home/` works, setting it to `localhost/settings/` also works, but when I change it to `localhost/stats/` it tries looking for the file or folder... not redirecting it to a variable to be used in PHP...
I did have a .PHP file sitting there before but removed it 2 days ago. Apache is still trying to find the file that was there. I've restarted my computer a dozen times with no luck.

My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9,a-z]+)$ /$1/$2/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9,a-z]+)/$ /index.php?function=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ /index.php?function=$1 [L]
```

What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a file called `stats.deadphp` in the root directory that was causing the issue. Deleting that cleared it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your httpd.conf or virtual host's conf file, you probably have an alias or something like that that makes it process /stats/ before the rules are reached.

Comment: It's a standard Apache build on a new Ubuntu install, with next to no alterations. (PHP and MySQL server installed)

Comment: Still... I'm pretty sure my FreeBSD VPS had awstats configured to show up on `/stats/` by default.